# Make an Mac app do the CMD + H command

Tags: objective-c, macos, command, hide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cocoa: Hide one application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989370/cocoa-hide-one-application)

Hey, I was wondering if it's possible to make a button do the CMD + H command on other running apps?

This was how I was thinking:

The user will get a window like the force quit window you can open by clicking on the Apple logo > Force Quit. This window displays all running apps. and instead of having a force quit button there it would be a Hide button. So the user select which app that should be hided and then click on the hide button.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are aware that you can hide applications from within the application switcher? So pressing "H" while cycling through open applications with cmd+tab will do exactly what you ask for - if I understood you right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you can do this with AppleScript. Something like

```
tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "AppName" to false
```

I've seen people make scripts like this and tie it to a Quicksilver trigger to do various things with other apps.